# using variable label in sjt.df command inside sjPlot package?

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, sjplot

considering the use of variable labels in sjmisc or sjplot package, i just want to know how can i use the variable labels that i can set with the set_label() command in the sjt.df() command.

This is an example:

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)

data("efc")
sjt.df(efc)
```

the result is not showing the variable labels, but as you can see:

```
get_label(efc$c12hour)
```

> [1] "average number of hours of care per week"

The variable labels are there.

Please help.
and Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need HTML-output, you can use `sjmisc::descr(efc)`. Use the `max.length`-argument to shorten labels.

Comment: Thanks, i was unable to answer before. i really was looking for a html output, i am teaching to some students and they are new in R and the html output help me to get their attention. If there is no way to do that i will use this way. Waiting for a html. Thanks again.